# What is the maximum amounts of bytes that can be uploaded to a storage contract?

Tags: transactions

In a storage contract that stores bytes in a container, what is the maximum amount of data that can be uploaded per transaction?

Comment: i don't think there's a fixed limit to the number of bytes you an send in a transaction. its comes down to cpu, net, transaction processing time limit, and ram if you want to store it in ram

Answer (score 1):

The chain constants can be found here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/e87d245da0e458edc66139c3ca59f71861bcc1dd/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works on mainnet but if you are running a private nodeos then there are two parameters you can check. First of all go to your nodeos installation folder and find config.ini file in which you will find two configurations

"max_block_cpu_usage" and "max_transaction_cpu_usage"  which will be the maximum limit of a transaction and block respectively . The values of these fields are in bytes. You can always change these values but remember that

"max_block_cpu_usage" > "max_transaction_cpu_usage"